# Sumif and Sumifs with open ranges gives #ERROR in one sheet, correct result in other

Tags: google-sheets

Here's my test sheet:

Localization is USA with timezone GMT+1
I've tried substituting ',' with ';' to no avail.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pZku_X6b49uMhKivnv3N1uv6sekYrhY12IlUct_Zudc/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see, sumif/sumifs with open ranges returns #ERROR.

```
=sumifs(!b2:b,!a1:a,">=2/1/2018",!a1:a,"<=2/2/2018")
```

I know it should work because I've done `sumifs` with open ranges before and worked as intended.

Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome. While I was taking a look into your spreadsheet some else was editing so I can't see the formula that was causing the error. To prevent this situations, please share your spreadsheet to anyone with the link can view only **and** include the formula in the question as the spreadsheet could not be accesible in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First formula :

Don't use `=!A1:A` or `=!A1` these are not ranges or cell addresses. The operator `!` is used to reference a range in a specific tab like this : `=Sheet1!A1`

Using `=A:A` the  `sumif` works.
In E3 : `=sumif(A:A,">=2/1/2018",B:B)`

---

Second formula error :  `Argument must be a range.` It's because filtering `B:B` breaks the formula in the third argument of `=sumif`.

Try this in `E4` instead :

```
=sumif(filter(A:A,A:A<>"",B:B<>0),">=2/1/2018",B:B)
```

Same deal for `sumifs`. `F4` is now :

```
=sumifs(B:B,B:B,"<>0",A:A,"<>",A:A,">=2/1/2018",A:A,"<=2/2/2018")
```